# How to write callbacks to get predictions from fit_generator() in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

There is no doubt that we can define our own callbacks to get the loss of the batch from fit_generator in keras as follow:

```
class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []
    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

I wonder if there is a convienient way to get the **predictions of each samples** in batch like the way to get the loss of each batch.

I have searched the solution for a long time but no hints about it, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2859#issuecomment-291384157 Look at this one.  It suggests to put the targets as inputs and compute the prediction inside of the callback. Not very neat but that's F. Chollet's solution.

Comment: @NassimBen thanks for your hint, the probability/prediction is the  intermediate product, thus, I woder if there is a way to call them directly in fit_generator(), compute the prediction inside the callback is too expensive for many images. Thank you once again!

Comment: Sorry but apparently there is none with the Keras API, but feel free to dive into the code and maybe try to modify keras... not sure it's possible, nor easy :)